# How to remove gnome completely and install unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I recently removed mate desktop environment and installed unity desktop . I found out that there are a lot of gnome processes currently going in task manager. What are they?
If I remove gnome completely will there be any problem with unity ?
Does unity uses anything from gnome?

Comment: You haven't said what release you are talking about, however Unity is built on GTK3 and GNOME's backend, with Unity replacing GNOME Shell. Are you sure you're not talking about the GTK3 backend (which is also used by MATE too, though less of it than Unity used), and YES Unity uses much of GNOME software (Unity replaces the top UI or GNOME Shell)

Comment: i am currently using openbox

Comment: Openbox?  Openbox is a *window manager* and how does it relate?   Your OS/release details (what flavor and release of Ubuntu are you using) would be a start.  (Lubuntu uses `openbox` as it's WM, where as Debian use `xfwm4` from the XFCE project for LXDE & LXQt desktops, but I don't see the connection between WM & DE)

Comment: I am using LTS 20.04

Comment: If you remove gnome completely without breaking your openbox installation, then reinstalling unity-desktop will bring in all components you might have deleted that are needed to run Unity. You could also remove things from a terminal recovery prompt with network access, and then reinstall unity and or openbox.